# How do you extract tightly-coupled code into an external library?

Tags: javascript, html, paradigms

This is a generic question about paradigms, and I apologize if this is an inappropriate place to ask.  Polite recommendations on the correct place to ask this will be appreciated :)

I'm working for a company that has a separate codebase for each of its websites.  I've been asked to take a sizable piece of functionality out of one codebase and put it into an external library, so that multiple codebases can make use of it.

The problem is that the code is tightly coupled to the codebase it was built in, and I'm having a difficult time extracting it.  I've approached this problem from multiple angles, and restarted from scratch each time.  Each time, I start running into complexities, and it feels like I'm approaching the problem the wrong way.  I was wondering if anyone else has had experience doing this, or if there is a recommeneded way to proceed?

Here's what I've tried:

- I copied the relevant files into a new project, carefully replacing each reference to the old codebase with vanilla javascript.  This has been a laborious process, and I keep running into issues I can't solve
- I placed a very basic HTML file in the old codebase, as well as a blank javascript file.  I've been cut and pasting functions one at a time into that javascript file, and calling them in the old codebase as well as the basic HTML file.
- I created another new project, and copy and pasted functions one at a time into the new project.

Each approach has presented me with its own challenges, but I can't get around the fact that the original code is so tightly coupled to the original codebase that progress is very slow, and I'm beginning to question whether any of the code is salvageable.

Comment: Start with refactoring the old code, extracting pure functions out of it etc. Avoid using globals in your code (globals being any external variables that are defined outside of your current class/function/module). When finished, extract the code to external module (should be simple copy&paste). Then provide a wrapper to tie old code with the new external module.

Comment: Re "best place to ask", check out http://stackexchange.com/sites# for other communities that may be useful. I don't know what's on topic at  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ but it looks interesting.

Answer (score 1):

The old code may not be salvageable, and it's more than reasonable to reach a point where you go back and say so.

The typical goal I have in cases such as these, cases where nearly all of the old code is unsalvageable but something new needs to not only take over for it, but quickly be used by old and new codebases alike, is to refactor the code into models, services, and components (less MVC and more 'data, how you get and change data, and how you view and interact with data').

In cases where you are building something to replicate the old, but get to write it from scratch, I treat it like it's brand new, and start from the interfaces, first. By knowing what the outer-edges *should* look like, and by keeping the internal code clean, and leaning on DI (the principle, not any wrapper in particular), I build the system I think I should be able to have, such that new projects/products can happily integrate with the right thing.

...for projects which need to have a product revamped, inside of a busted old system, I take nearly the same tack; I design the interface that I want, I make sure that everything is DI friendly (this becomes more important, here), and then I build a facade that looks exactly like how the old bustedness is called and used, and inside of that facade, I instantiate the sane system, I transform whatever the old, awful data points were, into our new models, I do whatever it is my system needs to do, and on the way out of the system, I transform our awesome new models into the terrifying results that the old system was responsible for making.

The latest such thing is a new platform which hosts new APIs.
The APIs, however, talk to awful, old, stateful, session-based web-services, which make horizontal-scaling absolutely impossible (not what you want to hear, when your goal is to distribute the new platform on Node, on AWS).

The solution was to build the APIs exactly as we expect them; get the interface to look as nice and be as useful as possible, while serving the actual needs of the API clients.

Then, we made sure that the modules which provided the APIs used DI for the service that acts as a connector to the old back-end.
That's so that we can simply swap out that service, when it comes time to connect to a better implementation of the system.
That service, however, needs transformers.

It needs one transformer to convert our awesome new request objects, into the scary old ball of mud that just kept growing.
Then it needs another transformer to turn the output from the ugly old data, into our new models, that our whole system uses.
Those transformers don't necessarily need to be injected into the service, because their implementation details are tied pretty tightly to the place that they're calling, and any update to the service, or any new service called will require transformer work for that specific service's implementation details.

Then there are problems on the front-end side, where communication used to take too much for granted, when talking to a server.

We now have transformers on the client side, which are used at the last possible second (actually, we wrote client-side services) to convert the old way of doing things to talk to the new form.

Any magic global data, which was randomly called in the middle of a process was factored into the service, the transform, and the API in general, if it serves a specific / reusable enough purpose.
Any of those magically grabbed pieces of information are now *explicitly* passed in. Some are client-only, and thus are either config data for instantiation, or are parameters for particular methods on services.
Session data is now explicitly passed back from the client, in the form of tokens/ids on each request that requires them (for now).
So the new platform stays 100% stateless (and thus scales wonderfully, from that aspect).

So long as all of that magical data gets pulled out of the internals, and passed through, the system can keep being refactored, without too much worry.
As soon as state and state-management exist on the inside of your system, it starts getting harder to work with, and harder to refactor (but you already know that).

Doing a refactor of a product which never leaves the page (ie: involves no APIs/services, or at least none that are tightly coupled to your front-end), isn't really much different.

Remove global state, by explicitly forcing it to be passed into your system (build time, call-time, whenever fits the data's purpose).
If there are async race conditions with moving parts that touch too many things, see if you can resolve them with promises, to get you out of nested callback hell.
My team is now largely using set-based programming (`.map`, `.filter`, `.reduce`, over arrays) and functional programming, in general, to simplify much of the code we look at and write, as each new function may only be 3-5 lines long (some being one-liners).

So our services will tend to be structured in an OOP sort of way, but as much as possible, will remain pure (no outer state modified by/for function calls), and the internals of those calls will typically look much more like chained or composed functional programming.

This has less to do with the overall refactor, and more to do with the micro refactors, as we build our systems.
For the macro-level, it's really your interface, and the facade you wrap the old stuff in, and the removal of all global state (which functional helps with) which make the difference.

The other alternative, of course, is to copy and paste the whole file/page, and start erasing things that you know aren't going to break, until you get to the things that might break, and continue from there. It's not pretty, it's not reusable, but I've been forced to do it a few times in my life, and regretted it every time.